# SQL Sever contains not finding specifics values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In my database i have a column named index_description_column in the table products, and i've a record with `"2205607 GRAMPO FIX. ROLDANA 7/8" (1X9)"` data.

When i do the following query it brings de record as expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE CONTAINS(index_description_column, '"GRAMPO*" and "FIX*" AND "1*"')
```

But if a do the following query to match the 7/8 part with doesnt bring nothing

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE CONTAINS(index_description_column, '"GRAMPO*" and "FIX*" AND "7*"')
```

How can i made it work?

Comment: Sounds like it tokenizes the „/„ to two words (but not for „x“). I guess this should be changeable with the word breaker.

Comment: I don't have full-text catalogs enabled, but what's with the *? WIll it work without them, or with % instead?

Comment: The * make all words starting with the text before to match. Its simular to % in like operations. (https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql)